# How to read data stored in MS Excel file?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

i'm trying to perform simple automated test on my Adobe Air Application. I decide to store some test data in external MS Excel file to decrease hardcode quantity. But I discovered, that this is not a trivial task, when you're working with Adobe Air.

Actually, i need to correct initialize an excelApp object, the rest part of logger is already implemented. I tried the following approach, but I can't find a package with **ActiveXObject** class defined.

```
excelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

Can you give some ideas, where can I find such a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple as3 xls reader library called [as3xls](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/) that should provide the functionality you need. However, if you need to write out excel files, it's a little bit rough.